# SQL query - add and update values at the beginning of a time series

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dealing with a SQL table called **lecture** with the following data:

```
datetime    value 
2019-01-01   20
2019-02-01   22
2019-03-01   25
2019-04-01   26
2019-05-01   28
2019-06-01   28
```

I used to calculate difference between values implementing the following code:

```
select T1.datetime
     , case when T1.lag_value <0 then 0 else T1.lag_value end as lag_value
  from (select datetime, value - lag(value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) lag_value 
from lecture) as T1;
```

And the result is the following:

```
datetime    value 
2019-01-01   20
2019-02-01   2
2019-03-01   3
2019-04-01   1
2019-05-01   2
2019-06-01   0
```

The thing I want to is the first value to be zero automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can default it using:

```
value - lag(value, 1, value) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)
```

or use `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce(values - lag(value) OVER (ORDER BY datetime), 0)
```